# Concatenation of property name (EL) in JSF

Tags: jsf, el

How can I concatenate the name of a property using the EL?

This is what I tried:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{someBean.getParts()}" var="part">  
        <h:inputTextarea value="#{someOtherBean.result}#{part}" />      
</ui:repeat>
```

But it didn't work.

The bean has the four property resultA, resultB, resultC and resultD. getParts() returns "A", "B", "C", and "D".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that can be made to work without changing the design. It's generally a bad idea in Java to have a design that requires you to access methods fields and properties through a name, and worse if the name is built from strings.

Possible solutions:

- have `getParts()` return "resultA", "resultB", etc. and access them `#{someOtherBean[getParts()]}`
- change the property names to `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and access them as `#{someOtherBean[getParts()]}`
- have a single property `result` that contains a `Map` with "A", "B", etc as keys and access the values as `#{someOtherBean.result[getParts()]}`

Answer (score 4):

It's quite possible though. You can use `<ui:param>` to prepare the dynamic property name and use the brace notation `[]` to access it.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{someBean.parts}" var="part">  
    <ui:param name="resultPart" value="result#{part}" />
    <h:inputTextarea value="#{someOtherBean[resultPart]}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

Needless to say that I agree with Michael that this is a smell in the model design.