# Concatenation inside a JSF expression

Tags: jsf, el

I'm trying to concatenate a number inside my JSF expression:

```
<h:dataTable class="seminaire" value = "#{seminaireControl.getList()}" var = "seminaire">

    <c:forEach begin="1" end="#{extraControl.getNb()}" var="nb">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">seminaire #{nb}</f:facet>
            <h:inputText value="#{seminaire.value+#{nb}"/>
        </h:column>
    </c:forEach>

</h:dataTable>
```

What I'm trying to have is something like `#{seminaire.value1}`, `#{seminaire.value2}`, ...

Comment: I think "#{seminaire.value}#{nb}" should work.

Comment: @Vebbie unfortunately no, the class Seminaire does not have the property 'value'.

My class only has properties value1, value2...

Comment: oh. Then you can write it as #{seminaire.['value'.concat(nb)]}

Comment: @Vebbie remove the first '.', then this is it.

Comment: I tried `${seminaire.value[nb]}` , `#{seminaire.['value'.concat(nb)]}`, `#{seminaire.[value.concat(nb)]}`, `#{seminaire.value[nb]}` but it's still not working :$

Comment: As @Selaron suggested by removing first dot, it will be "#{seminaire['value'.concat(nb)]}"

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood you `value="#{seminaire['value'.concat(nb)]}"` does work, thanks everyone

Comment: Hi, this is EL, not java, not html, not jsf and not java-ee. The duplicate contains all relevant info.

Comment: A better duplicate would be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249086/jsf-concatenation-of-property-name-el

Comment: @JasperdeVries: you might be right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concluding the above, to help other users for EL syntax to be used in proper manner.
(The + operator is in EL exclusively a sum operator.)

```
<h:dataTable class="seminaire" value = "#{seminaireControl.getList()}" var = "seminaire">

<c:forEach begin="1" end="#{extraControl.getNb()}" var="nb">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">seminaire #{nb}</f:facet>
        <h:inputText value="#{seminaire['value'.concat(nb)]}"/>
    </h:column>
</c:forEach>
```